# How can I import a Timer from Form1 to Form2?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `getDataRefreshRate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` `Timer` in `Form1` that gets some readings from Arduino at an interval using `SerialPort`. Then I have another `Form2` that displays the data in a `chart`. So, how can I use this `getDataRefreshRate()` `Timer` from `Form1` to update the `chart` in `Form2` as well? Or is this impossible?

Comment: Possible, you need to create Form2 as a child of Form1, then pass the value, it's basic OOP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a parametrized Form2 constructor Like below and field for timer

```
public class Form2
{
    private Timer parentTimer;
    public Form2(Timer parentTimer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.parentTimer = parentTimer;
    }
}
```

Now create object of Form2 Like below on Form1 and show

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(yourTimerObjectOnForm1);
frm2.Show();
```

and you can use parentTimer object that is created on Form1 in Form2

Comment: I've tried this. It works. However, the data that gets passed is short by one data means that my chart can never display the last data that is stored in the list in `Form1`

Comment: Only the reference of the list is passed therefore the fault is in you form1 data, look into it.